# Freeform - view submission on frontend based on GUID

Tags: solspace-freeform

I need to do the following.

A user completes a form and is emailed a url with a GUID on the end.  When the user clicks the link they are taken to the site and can view their submission.

www.mybeltingsite.com/90c202f2-302b-4d8b-bf06-2ffdb706532d

I'd like to do something like

```
{exp:freeform:entries entry_id="{last_segment}" }
  {!-- Stuff  --}
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

or

```
{exp:freeform:entries my_form_custom_field="{last_segment}" }   
  {!-- Stuff  --} 
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

Where the my_form_custom_field is the GUID.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

did you try to use parameter [search:FIELD_NAME=](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/#search_field_name)

```
{exp:freeform:entries search:my_form_custom_field="{last_segment}" }   
  {!-- Stuff  --} 
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```